# Make REST API calls from SharePoint Online to my on-prem API Securely

Tags: javascript, api, rest, sharepoint

I have a piece of JavaScript that I need to give to a vendor.  They will incorporate that script into our O365 SharePoint tenant (I'm guessing in a master page).  The script calls a REST API that is on-prem to retrieve some info from our database and shows it on the SPO page.

The API uses OAuth 2.0, so the script will somehow need to get the App ID and API Key in order to make calls to get an access token and then subsequently, use that access token to make calls against the API.  I do not want to code those keys into the script (obviously).

How can I store the ID/Key securely somewhere NOT in the JS file so that it won't be visible to anyone who knows how to use developer tools?

Here is a modified snippet of the script to get the access token.
I want to replace (at least) the first 3 lines to securely generate the auth token. If at all possible, I'd like to replace all of the code to securely retrieve the access token.

```
// BEGIN: NEED TO SECURE
var appID = 'aaabbbccc';
var apiKey= 'somelongstring...';
var authorizationToken = SomeCodeToMakeFromAppIdAndKey(appID,apiKey);
// END: NEED TO SECURE

var endpointUrl = apiUrl + '/api/token';

return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: endpointUrl,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'basic ' + authorizationToken
    },
    data: "grant_type=client_credentials"
}).then(function(response) {
    // get the access token from the 'access_token' property of the data object
    return response.data.access_token;
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can't do it server side ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.  The script sits in on/runs from the SPO servers and I need to call my servers securely.  I could make a call to one of my servers and have it get the token, but I'm trying to figure out how to do that securely.  I'm already calling my servers for the API.

Comment: well you shouldn't have your key on  the client, get your access token and send it to the server to get your auth

Comment: That's what I'm asking how to do.  I need to know how to securely make a call from JS in SPO on the client to one of my servers.